# How would I move or extend my home partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

When I created the dual boot partitions for Ubuntu 18.04, I used the express installation because at first I didn't know what I was doing. I had all the partitions created on my 180GB SSD with a cumulative size of 75GB for Ubuntu. I set 50GB for the home partition. I have two more drives, a 1TB HDD and a 1.5TB backup HDD. Is it possible to move my home partition to the 1TB HDD and then have it backed up to the 1.5TB HDD? This is how I have it set up for windows so I know which drive has what. When I tried backing it up to the HDD Ubuntu denies me permission.

Comment: Keep /home/ on the ssh. Move the directories to the HDD. See `~./config/users-dirs.dirs`. /home/ can be as small as 10Gb that way. /home/ has to be on ext4. If the 1Tb is NTFS you can not put /home on it.